# use class inside a gemfile on rbs files

Tags: ruby, rbs

I am working in `.rbs` files in ruby and I and everything were working inside my app until I decided to declare the `Redis` type in the `.rbs` file.

I am using the gemfile `redis`

and then I have this function:

```
  def redis_connect
    Redis.new(host: REDIS_HOST, port: REDIS_PORT, password: REDIS_PASSWORD)
  end
```

which in the `.rbs` file looks like the next:

```
def redis_connect: () -> Redis
```

But I am getting the error `cannot find Redis`

is it possible to "type" Redis? or do I need to leave it `untyped`?

Thanks

Comment: not very familiar with RBS, but can't you just declare `class Redis` in the rbs file to tell it that's a class?

Comment: @Max no, that does not work. as the new `Redis` class is not the one generated by `Redis.new ...`

Comment: `rbs -r redis ...` to include the gem in your RBS prototyping or validation.

Comment: @ToddA.Jacobs that command seems not to be working (it triggers the hep) and when I ran any other I get a message like the next `.rbenv/versions/3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rbs-2.0.0/lib/rbs/environment_loader.rb:87:in 'block in each_dir': Cannot find type definitions for library: Redis ([nil]) (RBS::EnvironmentLoader::UnknownLibraryError)` any idea?